# How to check a string contain a certain value in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#define CHAR_SIZE 35

//Function to remove white space
char *remove_white_spaces(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            str[j++] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str;
}

void main()
{
    int i = 0; 
    char str[CHAR_SIZE];
    
    printf("\nKey in input: ");
    fgetchar();
    fgets(str , CHAR_SIZE, stdin);
    
    //Remove white space 
    remove_white_spaces(str);
    printf("%s",str);

    //for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    //printf("Length of the string: %d", i);

    if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1' )
    {
        printf("CORRECT");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Input");
    }

}
```

I want to check whether the user has type in the correct input. For example, I have key in 0 01111110 10100000000000000000000. After removing the white space, the str input became 00111111010100000000000000000000. From this str, I want to check that the user has only key in 0 and 1. The output of the result I got was correct which is shown below[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGWBM.png).
[Output of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGWBM.png)

However, when the user key in another value including 0 and 1. The output I suppose to get is the wrong input. But I obtained Correct as the result which is shown below[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88emV.png).

[Output of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88emV.png)

Additional question, How do I implement an if statement that the str has to only have 32 characters to continue otherwise it has to break and the user key has to key in 32 characters only. Can I do it in a while loop instead of an if statement so that the user would not need to run the code again?

Comment: What does `values` contain?  What is considered "correct input"?

Comment: What was `i` initialized to?

Comment: [Edit] and show a [mcve] along with input and expected vs. actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use strtok to extract your characters. Also there's a flaw in your logic. it should be `if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1'` to check if the value is '0' OR '1'. Here's a sample implementation you could refer to:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CHAR_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    char str[CHAR_SIZE];
    printf("\n Key in value: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(str, CHAR_SIZE, stdin);
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(str, "\n");
    int i = 0;
    tok++; //skip the first character which is a space
    while (*tok != 0x00)
    {

        if (*tok <= 0x31 && *tok >= 0x30)
            tok++;

        else
        {
            printf("Wrong number input ==> %c \n", *tok);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made changes to the code which is the if statement to  [if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1')] . However, I encounter a problem that if the user would to key in 012345. The output that I am supposed to get is wrong as it contains other values such as 3,4,5.  But the output that I have obtained is correct. How am I supposed to approach this issue.

Comment: would be helpful if you could share a code snippet

Comment: `(*tok <= 0x31 && *tok >= 0x30)`?!?!  Don't use magic numbers.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , I didnt use magic numbers as seen from my code. Would need some assistance on my code.

Comment: @clintonkavai , I have updated the code and would like to seek some assistance

Comment: @van1234 `0x31` and `0x30` are magic numbers.

Comment: @andrewhenle , Yes I understand. In the code I have implemented I did not use any magic number. The code u are looking at is from Clinton Kavai whereas mine is at the top which is the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are checking that `str[i]` should be equal to 0 **and** equal to 1 – and that doesn't make any sense, because an element in the array can be only one value, 0 **or** 1; so, you should test `if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1')`.
And, before that, you should initialize i: `int i = 0`.

**Edit**  you must loop over elements of the string

```
int check = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1')
         i++;
    else {
        check = 1;
        break;
    }
    
}
if (check == 0){
     print("CORRECT");
}
else {
    printf("WRONG INPUT");
}
```

Comment: you are not looping over all the elements of the str  
`while (str[i]) {
   if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1' )
    {
        printf("CORRECT");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Input");
    }
}`

Comment: How do I loop over all the elements?

Comment: I edit my answer based on you code check my answer

Answer (score 0):

initialize i:
putting the equivalent of C's

```
int i = 0;
```

in your prog lang before entering the while loop should do the job.